# Google Chrome 9 times out in accessing a website, I get this message; What's it mean?

Tags: google-chrome

I get the following error message when accessing a website in Google Chrome:

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113'
>
> Script timed out
>
> /catalogue/item.asp
>
> The maximum amount of time for a
>   script to execute was exceeded. You
>   can change this limit by specifying a
>   new value for the property
>   Server.ScriptTimeout or by changing
>   the value in the IIS administration
>   tools.

I'd like to increase the limit, because the site is just slow to respond.

Also, what are the IIS admin tools?

Comment: Is it your website? If not, there's nothing you can do. If it's your website, you need to ask this question in ServerFault.com (it will be migrated there).

Comment: @Randolph - if it is the OP's own web site Webmasters might be a better home.

Comment: IIS is the Internet Information Server software running on the web server.  This has nothing to do with your browser.  The "you" in the error message is directed toward the webmaster of the web site.

Comment: @RandolphPotter: No, it's not my website. So the msg is from the server of the site I'm trying to access. Thanks.

Comment: How is this too localized? Only one page in the whole world is too slow to respond? Slow response is unique to only this page? Thanks goodness someone managed to get in an answer before it was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing this error because the site you're visiting has a problem on their end which is causing the site or page to fail to load.

The IIS (Internet Information Services) administration tools are used by the system administrators of the web server that the site is hosted on. You as a visitor won't have access to these tools.

The only things you can do are wait for them to fix this or let them know of the error somehow.